# three.js filling gaps between edges

Tags: three.js, 3d, blender

I created a model in Blender of a block with a hole in it:

[image]

I export it as an .obj file, and import it in ThreeJS with the OBJLoader add-on.

When I use it in my app, it appears to draw a face over the sides of the hole:

[image]

[image]

Is there a setting I need to use in ThreeJS to avoid having it close over gaps like this? Or is the problem in how I'm creating the model? I'm totally lost here, any guidance appreciated.

EDIT: I discovered through trial-and-error that the problem is having irregularly-shaped faces, like the ones adjacent to the hole. I "solved" my problem by triangulating the model; while this changes its shape slightly, it ensures that every vertex in the hole is part of a triangle face, which seems to be the magic answer.

I'm still very curious about *why* this is, especially since the triangulation has made the corners of the box a bit weird.

EDIT 2: Sorry for the delay. Here's the blender file: https://gofile.io/?c=EoxH1r

Comment: Can you please share the `blend` file in this thread?

Comment: Certainly! I'm not home right now but I'll upload it in a few hours. Sorry for not including it originally!

Comment: @Mugen87 I added the .blend file. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: I've exported the asset to `glTF` instead of `OBJ` and verified it the followng `three.js` based viewer: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/. The result looks correct. `glTF` is actually the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. So using `glTF` might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87! Appreciate you taking the time :) I'll experiment with glTF format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of [ngons](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/ngons-triangles-bad) (polygons with more than 4 sides).

Modelling for three.js is just like modelling for games, so it is best to avoid polygons with more than 4 sides because when the renderer (or video card, I dunno) tries to render the model, it has to apply triangulation and may do it in an unexpected way.

As you said, applying triangulation to the model fixed the issue, but automatically applying triangulation in your modelling app may also yield unexpected results. So your best bet is to alter the model so you get the results you expect.

Here is a youtube video I found that seems to explain a lot about ngons.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjnCV2PIkKA
(though I only watched the first minute or so)

Here is an example of how I would do it, red lines representing added edges. Remember to do it all the way around on both sides and apply your smoothing groups before exporting.

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate it!

Silly question, but how are you adding these edges? I tried this by selecting two vertices (one "anchor" and one along the hole) and pressing `f`, for the "Make Edge/Face" tool. I suspect that this adds a face / does something funky, though, since it creates visible lines along the model's face. Is there a better way to add edges to a shape?

Comment: the image I posted, I just draw lines in photoshop to demonstrate it. How you join 2 verticies will depend on the 3d software you are using. A quick search on google should yield results for whatever software you use.